# Map class as some sql type in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, orm, complextype

how to map my class as a sql type in EF.

```
public class Car {
    public Car(double cid) {
        //calc
    }

    public double cid {
        get { /*my code to generate cid*/ }
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    // and other property an method
}
```

This class generated a unique code that represent a instance of car, this class has multiple constructors and properties and methods. I don't want map `Car` as a table in database, I want store `cid` and use `Car(double cid)` to create a instance of this class for use it.

```
public class Company {
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Car Car { get; set; }
}
```

The target table:

[image: The target table]

Code:

```
Car c = new Car(14612312);
Company com = new Company { "com1", c };
CompanyService.Add(com);

var com = CompanyService.getCompany(1);
Car c = com.Car;
```

Should I use `ComplexType` ?
Or can i define  explicit (implicit) operator to cast ? how can cast to db float type in EF automatically?

```
 public static explicit operator double(Car c){
     return c.cid ;
 }
```

Comment: what is your back end ? MSSQL or else?

Comment: @Sampath thanks ; i use MSSQL

Comment: why dont you add another column of this type and ignore the navigation property (since you won't be mapping the type anyways)?

Comment: @DevilSuichiro thanks for reply .
 I don't add any table because the 'Car' class only calculator and it don't need to store any data in database or file , generate a code and decode that.

Comment: yes. thats why you can just add the FK without declaring it as such, and ignore the car navigation property in the model, you don't need to map it in this context.

Comment: True, but this simple example of what I am doing.
i want  provide a solution for users of my class library.
For example, using implicit or explicit cast class to float and create a instance of class after read from database with float number.
@DevilSuichiro Thanks again :-)